# Laravel blank page issue - Migrating from Linux to Windows

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project running on Linux server without any issue. The files are in /public_html directory and "laravel" directory is out of public_html. It has mySQL 5.6 and PHP 7.1. The project works completely fine.

Now, we have decided to move this on windows server. I have setup same PHP and mySQL on new windows server. I have double checked and this is correct.

I have imported entire database to windows and files have been moved as below:

> The files from /home/abcuser/public_html/ directory to
>   C:\HostingSpace\abc.com\wwwroot
>
> The files from /home/abcuser/laravel directory to
>   C:\HostingSpace\abc.com\laravel

The IIS has site path as below:

> C:\HostingSpace\abc.com\wwwroot

I set all required permissions to these directories and updated database connection in .env file.

I am now getting blank page with no error message. Do I still need to make any changes in code? Did anyone has experienced the same?

Comment: PHP is pretty notorious for blank paging - see PHP white screen of death. Have you set the error levels in php.ini etc?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death Solve the missing errors or find the errors first, then figure out what is going on.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` maybe it is cache issue?

Comment: Maybe a URL rewrite module configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. Made some progress. After enabling detailed error, I found that mbstring was missing. I have enabled it and it still says: ERROR: The requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this fixed..

I had to enable some PHP extensions. What I did is:

> - Checked the list of disabled PHP extensions from IIS of concerned
>     site.
> - Checked whether the particular extension is enabled in oldserver where
>     it is working.
> - And Enabled it as needed.

[image]